# Another Chrome issue! Random scrolling?

Tags: google-chrome, scroll

For some reason, on two different websites made by me, and on NO other sites, Chrome will randomly scroll down by a variable amount whenever a new page is loaded, and sometimes even at other times (in particular when an object is being drag-dropped).

There is absolutely no reference to any `scrollTop` anywhere in the code for either site, and both sites have code that is completely written from scratch (so there is no common code I might have copy-pasted). Also, there is no `#` fragment in the URLs (whenever there are it scrolls to the correct position).

Has anyone else ever heard of Chrome just scrolling without cause? Anything that might be able to fix without reassigning `scrollTop` every time an action is taken?

Comment: Have you established if it's common to all Chrome users or just you? Could we possibly see these sites in action?

Comment: Site 1 is http://pokefarm.org/ - the problem seems to manifest itself most obviously on the forums, due to the pages being longer in general, but it doesn't seem limited to that section. Site 2 is still in Alpha stages, so I can't give access to that. However we also observed that reloading an iframe on a page also causes the main window to scroll down a fair amount. I will try to find out if other Chrome users might be experiencing the issue. I have the latest version - just throwing that out there ;)

Comment: @DJohnson I have started the poll on my site to ask users if they're having similar issues. See the poll [here](http://pokefarm.org/forum_thread?tid=118295)

Comment: I personally couldn't reproduce this on the latest Chrome in OSX or Windows and looking at your poll results it seems to be pretty inconsistent. My suggestion would be to try and find a finite number of steps which will reproduce the issue on a given page and then start removing/commenting out bits of code until the problem stops occurring. This way you can narrow down what's causing the issue.

Comment: Well, I tested it on a page that literally had no JS code at all. It still happened. I think this may be more a bug in Chrome itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by a bad Chrome "auto-refresh plus" addon that was actually adding an ad banner to the end of the page and attempting to scroll to it on pageload - it failed to scroll to the bottom because of images shifting the page height down.

Uninstalled the addon, and the problem hasn't occurred since.

Thanks to those who tried to help!

Comment: Wow... this one just nailed me as well. I installed Auto Refresh Plus and Chrome would override the hashes # that are supposed to jump directly to an answer on SO. For some reason though, only SO and SE is affected.